# How to install source/javadoc for Eclipse PDE?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jface

I have installed Plugin Development Environment on my Eclipse 3.8 via  http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno update site. Now in PDE projects under the "Plugin Dependencies" tree I see that all PDE JARs have attached source set to the same JARs. Yet, the JARs do not contain any sources - only class files.

Because of this I see no Javadoc for PDE/JFace classes and get ugly arg0, arg1, etc for auto-generated code.

Where and how can I get sources or Javadoc for PDE/JFace?

Comment: Where did you get your eclipse 3.8 without PDE installed?  The 3.8 eclipse SDK includes PDE and all of the source plugins.

Comment: Here: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.8-201206081200/ see "Platform Runtime Binary". I like building my Eclipse form scratch.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, I tried to reproduce your problem.

- downloaded Eclipse Platform Runtime Binary from the location you provided
- installed Plugin Development Tools -> Neither source nor Javadocs

Now, the following worked for me:

- Help -> Install new Software
- Work with 'The Eclipse Project Updates' (not the Juno main site!)
- installed 'Eclipse RCP Plugin Developer Resources'

This gave me sources and Javadocs for all the Plugin Dependencies in a newly created 'Hello World' Plugin Project. The size of the Eclipse installation increase by only 10 MB to a total of 116 MB.

Comment: And there are SDK features for PDE and JDT as well.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you tobias_k,

This works great but further to this I had also to install these resources to get [IFolder](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IFolder.html) javadoc for instance :

- **Eclipse Platform SDK**
- **PDE/API Tools Envirnement Descriptions**

Which was not installed in my Eclipse distribution.
Hope this helps someone !

Comment: I needed to see source of `org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart` and installing **Eclipse Platform SDK** worked for this purpose.

Comment: In general, there are many "xxx SDK" or "xxx Developer Resources" packages which contain various parts of the source code. Depending on which sources you need access to you need to pick the respective package to install. For instance, JDT stuff for launch configurations such as "AbstractLaunchShortcut" are in "Eclipse JDT Plug-in Developer Resources"