# How to get the source code of Eclipse

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Downloading Eclipse’s Source Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890757/downloading-eclipses-source-code)

I have known that I can get the eclipse SDK. But how can I watch the real code in the SDK. Can someone tell me the detail to watch them?

Comment: If you are asking how to view the Eclipse source while working with Eclipse, e.g. for developing Eclipse Plugins, take a look at this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12484617/1639625

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all source codes you need here:

http://git.eclipse.org/

Comment: Sorry to reply you so late. Thank you. But how can I use the *.git file?

Comment: This is the repository that you have to clone. Use it in this way (in example is egit): git clone http://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/egit/egit.git If you are not familiar with git you can read this: http://www.vogella.com/articles/Git/article.html or read the doc: http://git-scm.com/documentation

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse has a lot of sub projects and you probably need a couple of them to be able to build your own ide.

I would start with this [github](http://github.com/) project https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform and work from there.

Comment: Thank you. But how can I use the files?

Comment: In what way do you want to use them? I suspect there is a .project-file that you can open in eclipse if you want to edit the source.